# Beast mode to extract the date based on a pattern

Tags: domo

I am trying to extract the date from a field based on a pattern - If the first four characters of the field description are *SLD then I need to extract the date from the field description as output date else I need to take the date from the field orddate as the the output date..please find the table below:

| description | orddate | output Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *SLD 5/18/22 Rimel | 5/2/2022 | 5/18/2022 |
| SOLD mila | 5/3/2022 | 5/3/2022 |
| *SLD 5/23/22 345671 kilo | 5/15/2022 | 5/23/2022 |
| *SLD 5/14/22 jing ming | 5/1/2022 | 5/14/2022 |
| 123566 | 5/12/2022 | 5/12/2022 |

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
Case
    When Left(description,4) = '*SLD' Then 
        Replace( /*as months can have 1 or 2 digits, the resulting string could have some spaces that we need to clean*/
            Left( /* Remove characters after the date */
                Right(description, Len(description) - 5) /* Remove '*SLD ' */
                ,8
            )
            ,' ',''
        )
    Else orddate
End
```